# python class __getitem__ negative index handling

Tags: python, class, indexing

Is there a common function to do this? Right now I'm just doing the following (and overriding `__len__`)

```
if idx < 0:
    idx = len(self) + idx
if idx < 0 or idx >= len(self):
    raise IndexError, "array index (%d) out of range [0, %d)" %(idx, len(self))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems fine to me.  I don't think there is a better or built-in way to do that; overriding is about providing your own functionality, after all.

Edited to remove rather stupid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For those brought here by Google, I thought I'd add what I just came up with. Seems to work great for me.

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    # Do this until the index is greater than 0.
    while index < 0:
        # Index is a negative, so addition will subtract.
        index += len(self)
    if index >= len(self):
        raise IndexError
    # Replace with your custom interface.
    return self.__instance.GetValue(index)
```